# Adjust the screen size in IOS latest version for 3.5 and 4.0

Tags: ios

Now app is supporting only 3.5 screen only . for 4 inch alignment is going wrongly.
IOS apps can work in both screens.

Comment: r u using auto layout or auto resizing for your app

Comment: Are you creating the views in storyboard or programatically?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the app runs on both screens 3.5 and 4 inch, you will have to apply either auto layout or auto resizing to the UI elements. Here are more details on how to handle Views for different screens and orientations. [Check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html)

Answer (score 0):

For an app to support **orientations** and **multiple screen-sizes/devices** the developer has to apply one of the following two;

**1. [Auto Resizing Mask (Springs & Struts)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask)**

**2. [Auto Layout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)**

First one is fairly easy to use while Auto layout requires learning. With auto layout you can achieve almost anything but with the growing number of devices auto resizing mask can help only a little to support different devices.

Auto layout is the best way to support different devices and/or orientations.